# Trails Project didn't work the deployment

Tags: lightning-apps, xml, trailhead

I have been trying to learn a bit about LWC. In this process I found a trail:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-ebikes-sample-app

In which, I have found a couple of errors that I have not been able to solve. I was unable to configure the Experience Cloud site metadata file with the steps outlined in the instructions. I ran into the following error:

> **force-app\main\default\sites\E_Bikes.site-meta.xml  In field: indexPage - no ApexPage named CommunitiesLanding found**

This is my code:

```
<active>true
</active>

<allowHomePage>false
</allowHomePage>

<allowStandardAnswersPages>false
</allowStandardAnswersPages>

<allowStandardIdeasPages>false
</allowStandardIdeasPages>

<allowStandardLookups>false
</allowStandardLookups>

<allowStandardPortalPages>true
</allowStandardPortalPages>

<allowStandardSearch>false
</allowStandardSearch>

<authorizationRequiredPage>
    CommunitiesLogin
</authorizationRequiredPage>

<bandwidthExceededPage>
    BandwidthExceeded
</bandwidthExceededPage>

<browserXssProtection>true
</browserXssProtection>

<cachePublicVisualforcePagesInProxyServers>true
</cachePublicVisualforcePagesInProxyServers>

<clickjackProtectionLevel>SameOriginOnly</clickjackProtectionLevel>

<contentSniffingProtection>true
</contentSniffingProtection>

<enableAuraRequests>true
</enableAuraRequests>

<fileNotFoundPage>
    FileNotFound
</fileNotFoundPage>

<genericErrorPage>
    Exception
</genericErrorPage>

<inMaintenancePage>
    InMaintenance
</inMaintenancePage>

<indexPage>CommunitiesLanding</indexPage>

<masterLabel>
    E-Bikes
</masterLabel>

<referrerPolicyOriginWhenCrossOrigin>true
</referrerPolicyOriginWhenCrossOrigin>

<selfRegPage>
    CommunitiesSelfReg
</selfRegPage>

<siteAdmin>
    // my Playground username
</siteAdmin>

<siteGuestRecordDefaultOwner>
    // my Playground username
</siteGuestRecordDefaultOwner>

<siteType>ChatterNetwork</siteType>

<subdomain>
    playful-goat-dj9q91-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
</subdomain>

<urlPathPrefix>
    ebikes
</urlPathPrefix>
```

P.S.:
[image]

I've been doing the Trailhead Playground part. In fact, one of the points, I had to skip it because in my Playground it didn't appear according to the instructions.... I upload the screenshot about that items...

[image]
I put in green the item that I can't to complete!

[image]

Comment: Looking at the github repo, are you installing the code on scratch org or a developer org/trailhead playground? If its on an org, have you followed the instruction to `Configure the Experience Cloud site metadata file with the following steps:` from the repo correctly?

Comment: Thanks Raul, I've been doing the Trailhead Playground part. In fact, one of the points, I had to skip it because in my Playground it didn't appear according to the instructions....